# How to link a tkinter filedialoge.askdirectory() path into a Listbox in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I can't seem to find a direct answer, at least not for python 3.x. I imported the filedialog module and need to create a GUI where the user presses a button, chooses a **directory**, *not a file*, and then that directory path shows up in a Listbox. I have a suspicion that the Listbox may need to be written above the function, but I'm really not sure.

This is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import file_xfer_part2
import file_xfer_func


class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.maxsize(700, 500)
        self.master.minsize(700, 500)
        file_xfer_func.center_window(self, 700, 400)
        self.master.title("Directory Auto-Sync®")
        self.master.config(bg="#333")
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: file_xfer_func.close_app(self))
        arg = self.master

        self.get_lbl = tk.Label(
            self.master,
            font=("Helvetica", 16),
            fg="#fff",
            bg="#333",
            text="Choose Source Directory",
        )
        self.get_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(30, 0), pady=(100, 0))
        
        # ????????
        self.lst_dir = Listbox(self.master)
        self.lst_dir.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx=(30, 0), pady=(100, 0))
        # ????????

        def select_dir():
            dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

        self.get_btn = tk.Button(
            self.master, text="Browse", command=select_dir,
        )
        self.get_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(30, 0), pady=(10, 0))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As a newbie to python I really don't know where to even begin with the Listbox, as far as how to connect it to the filedialog.askdirectory() module. I really do appreciate your help. Thanks!

**`**UPDATE**`**

I converted the Listbox's into Entry's so users could manually type their paths as well.

**This is what I have so far:**

```py
# Import required modules
from datetime import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import filedialog
from file_transfer_assignment import file_xfer_func


class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.maxsize(700, 500)
        self.master.minsize(700, 500)
        file_xfer_func.center_window(self, 700, 400)
        self.master.title("Directory Auto-Sync®")
        self.master.config(bg="#333")
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: file_xfer_func.close_app(self))
        arg = self.master

        b = StringVar()
        e = StringVar()

        self.get_lbl = tk.Label(
            self.master,
            font=("Helvetica", 16),
            fg="#fff",
            bg="#333",
            text="Choose Source Directory",
        )
        self.get_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(190, 0), pady=(50, 0))

        def select_dir():
            dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
            x = dir_path + "/"
            self.lst_dir.insert(END, x)

        def relay_source():
            global source
            source = b.get()
            return source

        self.lst_dir = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40, textvariable=b)
        self.lst_dir.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(180, 0), pady=(5, 0))

        self.relay_btn = tk.Button(self.master, highlightbackground='#333', text='Submit', command=relay_source)
        self.relay_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(290, 0), pady=(10, 0))

        self.get_btn = tk.Button(self.master, highlightbackground='#333', text="Browse", command=select_dir)
        self.get_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(90, 0), pady=(10, 0))

        self.give_lbl = tk.Label(
            self.master,
            font=("Helvetica", 16),
            fg="#fff",
            bg="#333",
            text="Choose Destination Directory",
        )
        self.give_lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(190, 0), pady=(40, 0))

        def dest_dir():
            dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
            x = dir_path + "/"
            self.lst_dir_give.insert(END, x)

        def relay_dest():
            global dest
            d = e.get()
            dest = d
            return dest

        self.lst_dir_give = tk.Entry(self.master, width=40, textvariable=e)
        self.lst_dir_give.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(180, 0), pady=(5, 0))

        self.relay_btn_give = tk.Button(self.master, highlightbackground='#333', text='Submit', command=relay_dest)
        self.relay_btn_give.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(290, 0), pady=(10, 0))

        self.give_btn = tk.Button(self.master, highlightbackground='#333', text="Browse", command=dest_dir)
        self.give_btn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(90, 0), pady=(10, 0))

        def current_milli_time():
            x = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
            return x

        def move_files():
            files = os.listdir(relay_source)
            for i in files:
                paths = os.path.join(relay_source(), i)
                file_birth = os.stat(paths).st_birthtime
                file_modify = os.stat(paths).st_mtime
                if (current_milli_time() / 1000) - file_birth < 86400 or (
                        current_milli_time() / 1000
                ) - file_modify < 86400:
                    shutil.copy2(paths, relay_dest())
                else:
                    print("\n{} already in directory".format(paths))
            return

        self.move_btn = tk.Button(self.master, highlightbackground='#333', text="Move Files", command=move_files())
        self.move_btn.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=(200, 0), pady=(40, 0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**I am still getting this error:**

```
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not function
```

It is calling for error on line 114 which is the:

```py
 def move_files():
            files = os.listdir(relay_source)
            for i in files:
                paths = os.path.join(relay_source(), i)
                file_birth = os.stat(paths).st_birthtime
                file_modify = os.stat(paths).st_mtime
                if (current_milli_time() / 1000) - file_birth < 86400 or (
                        current_milli_time() / 1000
                ) - file_modify < 86400:
                    shutil.copy2(paths, relay_dest())
                else:
                    print("\n{} already in directory".format(paths))
            return
```

Still not sure why it's not pulling the path as just a string. Thanks again.

Comment: You can simply insert the `dir_path` into `self.lst_dir` inside `select_dir()` function.  And for your case, `self.lst_dir` can be created before or after the `select_dir()` function declaration.

Comment: Thank you! It's finally in the listbox, just vertical and stretched out. Any idea what attribute may fix that?

Comment: Please update your code with the changes.

Comment: Edited post with new code and issue.

Comment: As the error said, `relay_source` is a function.  So `os.listdir(relay_source)` should be `os.listdir(relay_source())`.